# Can Cayley-Menger Determinant Be Negative?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Cayley-Menger determinant is used to calculate the area of a triangle, volume of a tetrahedron etc.

Can be seen [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cayley-MengerDeterminant.html).

My question is;
If given only positive numbers, can Cayley-Menger determinant return a negative number? If so, how is it possible.

Comment: What do you mean by the last sentence? The point is that the formula can't tell if you've input a degenerate shape. If I want to compute the area of a triangle, I input the coordinates of the vertices to the formula. However, I could input three points which all lie on a line, and then the formula would output zero; which is in a sense the area of a degenerate triangle whose vertices are colinear.

Comment: Assume that there is no information about the coordinates. What if I give arbitrary values for edge lengths?

Comment: You mean that you input arbitrary values for $\beta_{ik}$? In that case I imagine you could make it take essentially any value at all, and it no longer has anything particularly to do with volumes. Zero is certainly achievable - for example, you could take all the $\beta_{ik}$s to be zero. Although as I point out in the last comment, it can be zero even when the $\beta_{ik}$s are distances between points.

Comment: @MattPressland I have edited my question. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: If you plug random lengths into a Cayley-Menger determinant, not only it can be zero, it can even be negative. In fact, for the case of tetrahedron in $\mathbb{R}^3$, a random set of lengths is realizable as the edge lengths of a non-degenerate tetrahedron if and only if the lengths satisfy triangular inequalities plus the Cayley-Menger determinant is positive.

Comment: For a proof of this, look at following paper [Edge lengths determining tetrahedrons](http://www.ems-ph.org/journals/show_pdf.php?issn=0013-6018&vol=64&iss=4&rank=4) by Karl Wirth and Andre S.Dreiding.

Answer (score 1):

@Cagirici \ Now that you have amended your question, I shall amend my answer.

For simplices which are the subject of the Cayley-Menger determinant in an even-numbered space, the determinant will be negative (or if degenerate, zero). A triangle or a pentachoron, for example.

In an odd-numbered space, the determinant will be positive (or if degenerate, zero). For a tetrahedron, for example.

Also, it matters not if for some reason the edge lengths are negative: Within the determinant they are squared.

Comment: I am so sorry, I've thought another thing and written another one. I intended to write *less than zero*. However, I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

It is zero iff the $n$ points embed in a hyperplane of dimension $n-2$ (three points on a line, four in a plane, etc.)